# How to use CakePHP's new Blowfish/Bcrypt for passwords

Tags: php, cakephp, bcrypt

Let's assume I am a total newbie to [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org). Let's further assume I have  written my User authentication exactly as it was written in [this tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) (Except for the mistake in it that made me waste more than an hour trying to figure out).

The [Migration Guide for 2.3](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-3-migration-guide.html) says that `bcrypt` has been added to the core hash algorithms. The only hint on how to actually achieve this is:

> You can now use Blowfish in your $authenticate array to allow bcrypt passwords to be used.

I have absolutely no idea what this means and how exactly I now can use bcrypt here. Googling it only led to the guide, which doesn't guide me. I would love to know how exactly I can activate this - where to put the option and what to write so it works, assuming my setup is like in the tutorial mentioned above.

Also, does this require a special version of PHP or would it work on any supported by CakePHP?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to use code that is not yet stable (2.3 is RC) docs will be scares and you will need to figure a few things out without docs. Even though there are no docs, the code is freely available and [has comments](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3/lib/Cake/Utility/Security.php#L82-L97)

Blowfish has its own [Auth adaptor](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3/lib/Cake/Test/Case/Controller/Component/Auth/BlowfishAuthenticateTest.php) you would need to use.

You could also view the [tests](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3/lib/Cake/Test/Case/Utility/SecurityTest.php#L109-L194) if the docs dont help, as the tests provide 100's of examples its far better than any docs.

Answer (score 3):

If you were already using Form authenticate successfully, you swap `'Form'` for `'Blowfish'` as your authenticate adaptor, i.e.

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $helpers = array("Html","Form", "Js", "Csv");
    public $components = array(
           'Auth' => array(
                'authenticate' => array(
                    'Blowfish' => array(/* your settings */) 
                )
            )
        );
        /* ... */
    }
```

Then you need to change your calls to `AuthComponent::password` (if you followed the tutorial probably in your User model's `beforeSave`) from

```
AuthComponent:password($pwd)
```

to

```
Security::hash($pwd,'blowfish');
```

because the password method of AuthComponent is implemented to use your Security.salt setting, which won't work with blowfish (it generates a new salt and stores it in the password hash).

Also note that the implementation in CakePHP prefixes the salt with $2a$ which had security problems before PHP 5.3.7 (see [this note](http://www.php.net/security/crypt_blowfish.php)).